# Query component integrated inside functional component

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

```js
const Users = () => (
  <Query query={getName}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return "Loading...";
      if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
      return (
        <div>
          <ul name="user">
            <li style={{ color: "white" }}>
              {data.user.firstname} - {data.user.lastname}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }}
  </Query>
);

const AppLayout = ({ children }) => (

        <div>
          <Users/>
        </div>
      
);
=================================================
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const getName = gql`
  {
    user {
      firstname
      lastname
    }
  }
`;

export default getName;
=============================================
```

Following are the code used for graphql to display the firstname and lastname using gql.

First is the functional component Users which includes the Query component inside it.
AppLayout component just wrap this Users Query component and 
getName is gql query used inside the Query property.

But when I am integrating then I am getting an error like the following:
{ Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: I can't figure it out from your snippet. Are you exporting the components? That error shows up when you forget to export some component. Check your imports/exports.

Comment: Yep, like @IonutAchim saids, the getName import should looks like this: `import getName from '../file/location';`